# Remove image dimensions from image url (Wordpress Woocommerce)

Tags: wordpress, image, woocommerce, dimensions

My images are displaying with cropped image dimensions at the end like so:

```
//localhost:8888/jasmine-hortop/wp-content/uploads/2017/12/croftersrights-300x111.jpg
```

How do I remove the "-300x111.jpg" in the image url?

Comment: you should try this :- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48009565/remove-image-dimensions-from-image-url-wordpress-woocommerce

Answer (score -1):

You need to find the piece of code that outputs the thumbnail, it's usually done with one of these functions:

```
get_the_post_thumbnail 
the_post_thumbnail 
wp_get_attachment_image 
wp_get_attachment_image_url
```

And then make sure that you pass `'full`' as `$size` parameter, e.g. `wp_get_attachment_image( 123, 'full' )` or `the_post_thumbnail('full')`

Comment: i tried bu this did not work for me